# refresh-on-save package no funciona en firefox

Tags: atom-editor

Hola buenas no me funciona el **refresh-on-save** package de atom, me sale este error, intento que funcione en firefox algun consejo?

*Browser Refresh on Save: 208:211: syntax error: Expected end of line, etc. but found property. (-2741)*

Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

podrias intentar en `Atom>Preferences>Packages>Browser-Refresh-on-Save>` desmarcar los navegadores que NO estas usando e intenar de nuevo y ver si te sale el mensaje de error.

https://github.com/atom/autosave/issues/65